# Replacing text after a specific pattern in C

Tags: c, char, logic

I have a char buffer which will be of the following format.

```
Somecontent
  .
  .
Content-Length: 1570

MoreContent
  . 
  .
EndofContent
```

I want to replace The more content part with something else say `Xyz` .  But now I need to change content-length value to the new length of xyz. Also more content has to be replaced by xyz.

I have been able to extract the content below content-length and modify it, but placing it back into the original buffer has been an issue for me.

The output should be:

```
    Somecontent
      .
      .
    Content-Length: 100

    xyz
```

I tried using strstr to find location of content-length, and use memcpy to copy contents before that, but it hasn;t worked. Can anyone suggest a method. The buffer is in `char *buf;`

Comment: You may want to post the code that isn't working.

Comment: Are you implementing HTTP client (POST)? (It's OK if you do it for learning, but you should reuse existing library otherwise). For this, you should know the length of the data to be sent before writing the value of Content-Length. If you implement HTTP 1.1, then you can do chunk encoding.

Comment: @nhahtdh Not related to HTTP. I will know the length of xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that, when you replace "More content" with "xyz", you're replacing, the end of "xyz" is the new "End of content".  Correct?  I'm also assuming the new "xyz" cannot overflow your buffer, correct?

In that case:

1) Search for "Content length".  Save the offset (for example, variable "ofs1").

2) Search for the start of "More content".  Save the offset (for example, variable "ofs2").

3) If you don't already know the new Content-Length, you can easily compute it as length(More Content) - Length(xyz)

4) Copy xyz over More content (e.g. memcpy)

5) Update "Content-Length".  Blank-pad, to keep the same #/digits.

6) Voila!  Done.